# Can't get names of subfolders using ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject') and JS

Tags: javascript, activex, hta, filesystemobject

I'm trying to get names of subfolders inside of a folder using JavaScript and Windows' `ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject')` in my HTA-file:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
var subfolders = fso.GetFolder('D:\path\to\myfolder\').SubFolders;
for(var i = 0; i < subfolders.length; i++) {
    alert(subfolders[i].Name);
}
```

OR

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
for(var subfolder in fso.GetFolder('D:\path\to\myfolder\').SubFolders) {
    alert(subfolder.Name);
}
```

But I get nothing in both cases. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've found this solution:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
var e = new Enumerator(fso.GetFolder('D:\path\to\myfolder\').SubFolders);
for(;!e.atEnd();e.moveNext()) {
    alert(e.item().Name);
}
```

Comment: It works... but why does the Only Right Way have to be so _ugly_?